# Connect underlying virtual machines of roles

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, roles, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I had previously connected to underlying vm instances of cloud services, for some troubleshooting and was sure, it mentioned in MS documentation that It can be done, but only for troubleshooting purpose.

This 1-2 years back, now that i look at instances of my worker role, the connect option is gone? have MS taken it out or Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Have you enabled RDP?

Comment: you are right! my bad!!